# What are the ranks do you earn drops?

Tags: steam, counter-strike-global-offensive

In the new update they made a new ranking system and on rank 2 I earned a drop. I was just wondering what ranks give you drops and which ones don't?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can receive one weapon drop per week. You will receive this drop the first time you increase your Rank during the week. Your level progress bar will indicate when you are eligible for an earned weapon. so the more  you play, there will be more chance to get random drops but you will sure get one weapon drop per week when you will increase your rank.

For more details on this please read [the operation information page](http://www.counter-strike.net/operationbloodhound/).

Comment: sorry for not linking link in good way as i tried but it is not appearing well so i post link like this..sorry in advance

Answer (score -5):

I think level 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30...

Comment: Outright wrong, as the accepted answer should say. And also since I got a drop on Rank 3 and Rank 5 and will get a drop on Rank 6.